# How to get unique values based on dictionary key, which is an element of an array in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

How to get unique values based on dictionary key, which is an element of an array in objective C ?

for example:

i am having an array of an Items

aryItem

```
  aryItem[0] = Dictionary{

               ItemCategory
               ItemName
               ItemPrice

               }

  aryItem[1] = Dictionary{

               ItemCategory
               ItemName
               ItemPrice

               }

   ...........
   ...........
  aryItem[n] = Dictionary{

               ItemCategory
               ItemName
               ItemPrice

               }
```

Now i want to get only unique ItemCategory , not duplicates. If i can write [[aryItem objectatIndex:i] valueForKey:ItemCategory] i get all categories, same category also included in this. I need only unique categories. I have an option searching whole array and then get unique Itemcategory objects, but i am looking for any short way to accomplish the same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think NSSet class is most suitable to collect unique values. You can create it using something like:

```
NSSet* categories = [NSSet setWithArray: [aryItem valueForKey: @"ItemCategory"]];
```

Comment: I have tried this, but its not working. No objects in NSSet Categories. Any other method ??

Comment: it should work. Check that valueForKey parameter is exactly the same with the key used in dictionary. Also try to check if aryItem contains items you expect